# Удалить повторяющийся подряд символ из строки php

Tags: php, строки

Имеется строка произвольной длины и содержания, в ней часто попадаются вставки из нескольких повторяющихся знаков вопроса, количество знаков может быть разным, как `??`, так и `????????`, и `????`, и т.д.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне удалить из строки такие вставки, если подряд идут более чем один вопросительный знак?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Если необходимо убрать повторяющиеся вопросительные знаки:

   ```
   $str = '??? ?? ??';
   $str = preg_replace('/(\?){2,}/', '$1', $str);
   //echo $str вернет ? ? ?
   ```
2. Если необходимо вырезать из строки вопросительные знаки, когда их количество больше одного:

   ```
   $str = 'example ? example1 ??? example2 ?? example3 ??';
   $str = preg_replace('/\?{2,}/', '', $str);
   //echo $str вернет example ? example1  example2  example3
   ```